# Using a self join to update a table with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to rewrite a MySQL update statement in Oracle. I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 20.4.1, and the MySQL code is:

```
UPDATE A
SET propertyaddress = ISNULL(A.propertyaddress, B.propertyaddress)
FROM nash_housing A
JOIN nash_housing B 
    ON A.parcelid = B.parcelid
    AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_
WHERE A.propertyaddress IS NULL;
```

**I have tried the following variations of code:**

```
MERGE INTO nash_housing A
USING nash_housing B
ON (
    A.parcelid = B.parcelid
    AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET A.propertyaddress = B.propertyaddress
WHERE A.propertyaddress IS NULL;
```

**ERROR** ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

```
UPDATE nash_housing A
    SET A.propertyaddress = (SELECT DISTINCT B.propertyaddress
                                FROM nash_housing B
                                WHERE A.parcelid = B.parcelid
                                AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_)
WHERE A.propertyaddress IS NULL
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM nash_housing B
            WHERE A.parcelid = B.parcelid
            AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_);
```

**ERROR** ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
UPDATE
(SELECT A.propertyaddress AS OLD, B.propertyaddress AS NEW
    FROM nash_housing A
    JOIN nash_housing B
    ON A.parcelid = B.parcelid
    AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_
    WHERE A.propertyaddress IS NULL
    ) C
SET C.OLD = C.NEW;
```

**ERROR** SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Thanks for any and all help with this.

Comment: The first two errors are both because `A.parcelid = B.parcelid AND A.uniqueid_ <> B.uniqueid_` matches more than one row, for at least one source row; which maybe isn't really surprising with the `<>` check. You need some criteria to decide which address to use when there is more than one; like a most-recent timestamp, or highest ID, etc.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: The idea behind the update statement is to replace NULL values for _propertyaddress_ for when two _parcelid_ values are the same, the _uniqueid_ will be different as it is a unique identifier. So the idea, as far as I understand it, is to use a self join to get the desired _propertyaddress_ to replace the NULL value.

Comment: @JohnK - the issue is getting **the** desired value to replace the null; you're finding **a** value, which is indeterminate when there are multiple possibilities, as Gordon said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second is closest.  You just have to limit the subquery to one row:

```
UPDATE nash_housing n
    SET propertyaddress = (SELECT n2.propertyaddress
                           FROM nash_housing n2
                           WHERE n2.parcelid = n.parcelid AND
                                 n2.uniqueid_ <> n.uniqueid_ AND
                                 rownum = 1
                          )
    WHERE n.propertyaddress IS NULL AND
          EXISTS (SELECT n2.propertyaddress
                  FROM nash_housing n2
                  WHERE n2.parcelid = n.parcelid AND
                        n2.uniqueid_ <> n.uniqueid_
                 );
```

Note:  Your table clearly has duplicates.  The MySQL version is updating using an *arbitrary* matching row.  The Oracle will do the same, although you might want to use an `ORDER BY` in the subquery to specify which row provides the value (such as the newest or oldest).

Also, I fixed the table aliases so they are meaningful.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it and it works as intended. Also for the updates and changes @Gordon